# Windows Server 2016: Hyper-V VM boot from and directly use SSD

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

My Server 2016 has a 512GB C: SSD and a 2TB D: spinning disk.
It also has an unused 512GB SSD.  Yes, I can create an 512 GB filesystem on this(E:), and then create something like a 510GB vhd[x] file(?) for it to use as its C: drive.

I worry that if my VM sees this disk as just a plain file it'll loss the NVMe advantages that allow very high IOPs.  Does a VHD[x] based "disk" get full NVMe benefits?

Is "pass-through" disks what I want for my VM's C: boot drive.  In Hyper-V Manager "Edit Disk" I only see options to use a VHD[x] file and no other options.  Where would I find the option to point my new VM at a physical device?

I a Windows novice, Linux expert, so forgive any misusage of terms.

Comment: I would appreciate you reviewing my answer to your question and if I was able to help you, marking answer as accepted by clicking on `v` under the answer's score. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 2012 R2 example, should work for you too.

When a VM created, open its settings and look at IDE or SCSI controller. For the system drive you may want to use IDE controller.

There you will find an option to use the Physical hard disk with a drop-down list, specifying the available disks. To have a disk listed there, you should prepare it and put offline in the Disk Management tool of the Hyper-V host server.

[image: VM Settings]

[image: Disk Management]